# How to specify a scalar multiplier for units when using Quantities?

Tags: python, numpy, units-of-measurement, quantities

The objective is to handle cell densities expressed as "1000/mm^3", i.e. thousands per cubic millimeter.

Currently I do this to handle "1/mm^3":

```
import quantities as pq
d1 = pq.Quantity(500000, "1/mm**3")
```

which gives:

```
array(500000) * 1/mm**3
```

But what I really need to do is to accept the values with units of "1000/mm^3". This should also be the form in which values are printed. When I try something like:

```
d1 = pq.Quantity(5, 1000/pq.mm**3)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: units must be a scalar Quantity with unit magnitude, got 1000.0 1/mm**3
```

And if I try:

```
a = pq.Quantity(500, "1000/mm**3")
```

The output is:

```
array(500) * 1/mm**3
```

i.e. The `1000` just gets ignored.
Any idea how can I fix this? Any workaround?

(The requirement arises from the standard practice followed in the domain.)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I have found is to create new units such as this:

```
k_per_mm3 = pq.UnitQuantity('1000/mm3', 1e3/pq.mm**3, symbol='1000/mm3')
d1 = pq.Quantity(500, k_per_mm3)
```

Then on printing 'd1', I get:

```
array(500) * 1000/mm3
```

which is what I required.

Is this the only way to do this? Or can the same be achieved with existing units (which is preferable)?